# How to convert if to while

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a condition that looks like this

```
if (savePosition >= 0 && savePosition <= sliderItemWidth) {
    savePosition = 0;
} else if (savePosition >= sliderItemWidth && savePosition <= sliderItemWidth * 2) {
    savePosition = sliderItemWidth;
} else if (savePosition >= sliderItemWidth && savePosition <= sliderItemWidth * 3) {
    savePosition = sliderItemWidth * 2;
} else if (savePosition >= sliderItemWidth && savePosition <= sliderItemWidth * 4) {
    savePosition = sliderItemWidth * 3;
}
```

I intuitively understand that I need to make it through "while" but I do not have enough knowledge to do it. Could you help me?

I also have the total number of slides in var = sliderItemCount = 7
I.e loop needs to be interrupted on 7

Comment: what do you do with `sliderItemCount`?

Comment: Dont use while, use switch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If right guarded, ie in the right interval, you could use this one.

```
savePosition = Math.floor(savePosition / sliderItemWidth) * sliderItemWidth;
```

Comment: This solution is fully fit. I was thinking about how to round the value. But I did not understand how to do it. Thank you!